# Is there a way to run TypeScript on the command line?

Tags: javascript, typescript, terminal, command-line-interface

I know that I can run JavaScript by running node through the command line, but is there a way to play around with TypeScript on the command line? Or must I use a text editor?

Comment: See https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you install ts-node for a project, you can then run it directly by typing in `npx ts-node`. It works similarly to Node's REPL.

[image]